# How to bind and display ListBoxItem index in ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a .NET 5 project with following Nuget Packages:

- HandyControls for UI
- Gong-Wpf-DragDrop for Drag and Drop elements in a List

I have a `XAML with a` ListBox`and a ViewModel with a`ObservableCollection` of Model.

The `ObservableCollection` is binded as `ItemSource` of `ListBox`

**What I want to achieve:**

When i Drag and Drop an item in a different position (or Add/Delete), I want the indexes to be refreshed.

Example:

*Before Drag/Drop*

[image]

*After Drag/Drop*

[image]

Actually, i binded the drophandler of gong-wpf-dragdrop
and at the end of the drop, i manually refresh every single Index in my list.

there is a way to do it easily? because actually i have to refresh indexes manually.

*Summarizing:*
When i reorder/delete/add items i want Model.Index of every item updated with the correct index position in ListBox.

**My Mandate is:**

- Show index (one based)
- Give the possibility to reorder the elements

I tried looking for similar questions but didn't find much that could help me.
Thanks in advance :)

---

**Model:**

```
public class Model : BindablePropertyBase
{
    private int index;
    private string name;

    public int Index
    {
        get { return index; }
        set
        {
            index = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And below a xaml with a simple binded list
**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<hc:Window x:Class="ListBoxIndexTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:hc="https://handyorg.github.io/handycontrol"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop;assembly=GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBoxIndexTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="600">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}"
             dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="10"
                      Background="Aqua">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" Margin="10,0"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                               Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

</hc:Window>

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindablePropertyBase, IDropTarget
{
    private ObservableCollection<Model> test_list;
    public ObservableCollection<Model> TestList
    {
        get 
        {
            return test_list;
        }
        set
        {
            test_list = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        TestList = new ObservableCollection<Model>()
        {
            new Model()
            {
                Index = 1,
                Name = "FirstModel"
            },
            new Model()
            {
                Index = 2,
                Name = "SecondModel"
            },
            new Model()
            {
                Index = 3,
                Name = "ThirdModel"
            }
        };
    }

    public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        Model sourceItem = dropInfo.Data as Model;
        Model targetItem = dropInfo.TargetItem as Model;

        if (sourceItem != null && targetItem != null)
        {
            dropInfo.DropTargetAdorner = DropTargetAdorners.Insert;
            dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
    }

    public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        Model sourceItem = dropInfo.Data as Model;
        Model targetItem = dropInfo.TargetItem as Model;

        if(sourceItem != null && targetItem != null)
        {
            int s_index = sourceItem.Index - 1;
            int t_index = targetItem.Index - 1;

            TestList.RemoveAt(s_index);
            TestList.Insert(t_index, sourceItem);

            RefreshAllIndexes();
        }
    }

    private void RefreshAllIndexes()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TestList.Count; i++)
        {
            TestList[i].Index = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is an out-of-the box way to bind to a container index in WPF. Your solution is actually easy to understand.

If you find yourself binding often to index, you could create your own attached property/value converter that internally climbs up the visual tree using [these helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?view=net-5.0) until it finds the parent `ItemsControl`and makes use of the [`IndexFromContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.indexfromcontainer?view=net-5.0%5D) method.

---

**Here is some code to get you started with this method:**

First a small helper function to climb up the visual tree looking for an item of generic type:

```cs
public static DependencyObject FindParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject {
    //We get the immediate parent item
    DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    //we've reached the end of the tree
    if (parentObject == null) {
        return null;
    }

    //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
    if (parentObject is T parent) {
        return parent;
    } else {
        return FindParentOfType<T>(parentObject);
    }
}
```

Then a value converter that takes a control as input value and returns its index in the first encountered `ItemsControl`:

```cs
public class ContainerToIndexConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        //Cast the passed value as an ItemsControl container
        DependencyObject container = value as ContentPresenter;
        if (container == null) {
            container = value as ContentControl;
        }

        //Finds the parent ItemsControl by looking up the visual tree
        var itemControls = (ItemsControl)FindParentOfType<ItemsControl>(container);
        //Gets the index of the container from the parent ItemsControl
        return itemControls.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And this is how you would use it in XAML:

```xml
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <!-- This will display the index of the list item. -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, Converter={StaticResource ContainerToIndexConverter}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: thanks for your kind reply! I was hoping for something cleaner, but for now I keep my solution.. i tried with a converter and IndexFromContainer but for some reason i did something wrong and is not working properly. i need to understand it better.
Thanks again! :)

Comment: @DavidePavani I've added some code to get you started. That should work for you.